# JavaFX SplitPane does not bubble up mouse event

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent, splitpane

I have a `BorderPane`. In this pane I have set as the **top** an `HBox` with several controls. In the **center** I have e `SplitPane` that has two canvases. I want to get a mouse move at the `BorderPane` when it bubbles up from the `SplitPane`.

If I use a `splitPane.setOnMouseMoved(...)` I get the event correctly. However a `BorderPane.setOnMouseMoved(...)` only works when the mouse hovers over the **top** (were the `HBox` is found).

It seems like the `SplitPane` is consuming the event. Can anyone confirm this? If so how do I get the even to bubble up? Note that when I apply a filter the even is detected at the `BorderPane` level on the way down.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most, if not all, skin implementations extend from [`SkinBase`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/SkinBase.html) which consumes all mouse events by default. You can configure this via the protected [`consumeMouseEvents(boolean)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/SkinBase.html#consumeMouseEvents(boolean)) method. As the method is protected you'll have to subclass the skin (or use reflection) to access it:

```
package com.example;

import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.control.skin.SplitPaneSkin;

public class MySplitPaneSkin extends SplitPaneSkin {

    public MySplitPaneSkin(SplitPane control) {
        super(control);
        consumeMouseEvents(false);
    }

}
```

*The skin classes became public API in JavaFX 9. If you're using JavaFX 8 you'll need to extend the internal skin class*.

You would then set the skin of the `SplitPane`.

```
SplitPane pane = ...;
pane.setSkin(new MySplitPaneSkin(pane));
```

You can also set the skin [using CSS](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#control) via the `-fx-skin` property:

```css
.split-pane {
    -fx-skin: com.example.MySplitPaneSkin;
}
```

Note that using CSS as above will set the skin for *all* `SplitPane`s covered by the stylesheet (unless you change their styleclass). You may wish to make this more specific by giving your `SplitPane` an ID and using `#id { ... }`.

Also, looking at the `SplitPaneSkin` implementation in JavaFX 11.0.2, an event handler is added to each divider which consumes all events. As this is a private implementation detail you can't change this behavior. In other words, even with the above code, mouse events won't bubble up to your `BorderPane` when the mouse is over a divider.

Another thing to consider is that any controls in the `SplitPane` will likely also consume mouse events. You'd need to apply something similar to the above for each such child control.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Unfortunately I am stuck with JavaFX 8. I also tried `  splitPane.setStyle("-fx-skin: com.example.MySplitPaneSkin;")` but that did not work. As for JavFX 11, any alternative you can think of. I want to avoid revisiting this issue in the future.

Comment: Since JavaFX 8 is pre-module-system you can subclass the internal `SplitPaneSkin` without worrying about module access errors. When you move to JavaFX 11+ the solution in the answer should work fine. Note, another way to set the `skin` of the `SplitPane` is to subclass `SplitPane` and override `createDefaultSkin`; you'll still need to subclass the skin class though.